# Displaying Categories and Sub Categories

Tags: categories

I know this has been asked and answered before but the solutions are not working for my so I was wondering if something has changed or if I am doing something wrong. Want to display my Categories, Child Cats, Grand Child-Cats. This is my code:

```
function list_areas () {
$provincearg = array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'area',
                            'hide_empty' => false,
                            'parent'=> 0,
                        );
    $provinces = get_terms ($provincearg);
        foreach ($provinces as $province) {
            echo '<h2>' .$province -> name. '</h2>';

            $municipalarg = array (
                                    'taxonomy' => 'area',
                                    'hide_empty' => false,
                                    'parent'=> $province -> term_id,
                                    );
            $municipalities = get_terms ($municipalarg);

            echo '<ul>';
                foreach ($municipalities as $municipality) {
                    echo '<li>' .$municipality -> name. '</li>';
                }
            echo '<ul>';
        }
}
```

It outputs the Category but not the sub categories. I even went as far as puting in the 'parent' id, when I do this nothing gets displayed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: An update: This code works for my categories but not my custom categories. 

I didn't ad the custom taxonomy via the admin panel. I loaded it via a CSV file. I am not sure if somehow that affects the wordpress fucntions somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve categories and sub-categories this way.

```
<?php 

$list_categories = get_categories( $args );
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<div class='productsubmenu'>";
echo "<ul>";

foreach ($list_categories as $cat)
{           

if($cat->category_parent == 0)
{
$category_id = $cat->term_id;

echo '<li class="parent '.$my.' "><a href="'.get_term_link( $cat ) . '">'.$cat->name.'</a>';


$args2 = array(
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
'child_of' => 0,
'parent' => $category_id,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'show_count' => $show_count,
'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
'title_li' => $title,
'hide_empty' => $empty

);
$args = array(
'hierarchical' => 1,
'show_option_none' => '',
'hide_empty' => 1,
'parent' => $parent_cat_ID,
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args2);
echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';

foreach ($subcats as $sc) { 
$link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
echo '<li class="" ><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
}


}
echo '</ul>';
echo "</li>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after strugggling and rewriting the code. I have finally solved this.

The issue was not with the code, the issue was when I registered my custom taxonomy, I spelled hierarchical incorrectly which is why it wouldn't get the child terms.